# Web app Views not updated after ftp publish (After upgrading from Net Core 1.x - 2.2)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I recently upgraded my .Net Core web app from 1.x to 2.2 and it seems that the views updated once but doesn't update after a fresh ftp upload to my Linux server running nginx. I have removed all old code from my publish folder and the folder on the server to ensure old code can't be interfering before doing a fresh publish.

The previous issue was that I had DefaultUI for my IdentityUser at my startup class which I have since removed. I have fixed the login pages to original state yet when I upload and restart the nginx server I do not see the new login page.